# BibTeX equivalent with CiteULike support?

Tags: bibtex

There was recently a question about [finding BibTeX formatted citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/143/what-are-good-sites-to-find-citations-in-bibtex-format), which listed [CiteULike](http://www.citeulike.org). I would love to take the shortcut, and replace the BibTeX executable with *cultex*, which takes CiteULike is replacement for the foo.bib file.

Is there such a utility yet, and/or is there critical mass to develop such a BibTeX replacement?

Comment: cultex?  Is this vapourware?

Comment: It's an idea... I thought that was clear when I asked about 'critical mass to develop'... :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

biblatex with biber supports this now. You can now use a remote URI which returns a valid datasource file (like .bib). See the biblatex manual, section 3.5.1 for examples using citeulike. You have to be using biber as the backend.

Comment: And you have to use `\addbibresource` instead of `\bibliography` as described in the [question about differences between these two commands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21439/is-there-any-advantage-to-using-addbibresource-over-bibliography).

Answer (score 5):

You are aware of [biblatex-biber](http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/), I hope. This does have a critical mass, but is taking a different approach to CiteULike. One of the big challenges is storing bibliographic information for arts and humanities. The idea in biblatex-biber is to use a suitable XML format for the job.

Answer (score 2):

I found the simplest approach to [use CiteULike groups](http://chem-bla-ics.blogspot.com/2011/02/integrating-citeulike-in-latex-based.html), and use a Makefile like this:

```
book.bib:
        @wget -O book.bib http://www.citeulike.org/bibtex/group/14384
```

For [group 14384](http://www.citeulike.org/bibtex/group/14384).

Comment: Why isn't "@wget -O book.bib http://www.citeulike.org/bibtex/group/14384" enough?

Comment: Ah... well, sometimes I add stuff from other sources before the wget command :) I will update the code here.