# Is there any advantage to using \addbibresource over \bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, biber, best-practices

I've always used `\bibliography` to tell BibTeX where my bibliography is, and when I moved to `biblatex`, I didn't change. I see a lot of `biblatex` answers use `\addbibresource` instead.

What is the advantage of `\addbibresource` over `\bibliography`?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

`\addbibresource` features an optional argument that allows you (among other things) to specify the location of a (local or remote) resource and the date type of the resource (e.g., `bibtex`, `ris`). See section 3.7.1 of the [`biblatex` documentation (ver. 3.15, dated August 19, 2020)](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) for details.

Note that when using `\addbibresource` (which was introduced in `biblatex` v1.2), *"ﬁles must be speciﬁed with their full name, including the extension"*, i.e., instead of

```
\bibliography{<mybibfile>}
```

you must use (assuming the standard `.bib` file format)

```
\addbibresource{<mybibfile>.bib}
```

EDIT: Two additional notes about using `\addbibresource`:

- Contrary to `\bibliography`, one can't use a comma-separated list to load multiple `.bib` files (`\bibliography{bibfile1,bibfile2}`). Instead, one must invoke `\addbibresource` multiple times.
- As PLK points out in his comment, loading a remote bibliography resource requires `biber` as backend.

Comment: You can link directly to a citeulike bibliography!? That's amazing. That would make collaboration much easier...

Comment: Yes, as long as the remote source returns a parseable bibtex data file. So, you could say:

`\addbibresource[location=remote]{http://www.citeulike.org/bibtex/group/9517}`

See section 3.5.1 of the biblatex manual. This feature is biber only (it's all done by biber in the backend).

Comment: @PLK do you know if there is any way of using addbibresources to remote files located on a dropbox server and refered to by something like:
\addbibresource[location=remote,type=file]{https://www.dropbox.com/s/h1x0l95hbcypij/TestBibliography.bib?dl=1} that would be great! thanks!

Comment: Along as the url returns a .bib file, it should be fine.

Comment: Also note that according to section 3.6.1 of the biblatex documentation, "[`\bibliography`] is deprecated. Please consider using `\addbibresource` instead." It's only still available for the purpose of backwards compatibility.