# BibTeX generator for webpages

Tags: bibtex

Is there any site/tool that get a web page URL and generate a BibTeX entry for it automatically.

Zotero will do this after some steps, but I just use Opera and Zotero has not not an Opera-Extension (yet).

I am looking for a web site like ottobib.com. It is given an ISBN an returns citation instantly. I need a site that simply get URL and return web citation.

Comment: May be Mendeley?

Comment: @HarishKumar Its Web Importer works with opera, but it just import articles no wepage and no-bibtex

Comment: Borderline for on/off-topic: seems more about web applications than TeX in many ways.

Comment: @JosephWright BibTeX (just) is  used in TeX world. So is it not better that all question about BibTeX be asked here? So where is better place for this question?

Comment: @Reza The issue here is that an answer seems to require web programming and some insight into the data formats of webpages/online databases, rather than into TeX, BibTeX, _etc._ As such, the question is 'is it likely that someone with expertises in TeX be able to answer'. I'd certainly say this is a borderline case (I can see arguments in favour of the question as well as against). I suggest you open a question on the meta site, pointing to this and making the case for reopening. We can then discuss it there.

Comment: There are at least three site that do exactly what you asked for: [Connotea](http://www.connotea.org/), [CiteULike](http://www.citeulike.org/) and [Bibsonomy](http://www.bibsonomy.org/).

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33619/latex-and-bibliography-management-tools

Comment: @Reza Sorry, mabe I misunderstood your question: Does the URL point to a journal article (like this URL http://www.springerlink.com/content/d0cv6n1pe7ecacf1/ ) or is it just any homepage like http://www.example.com/ ? The sites I linked to can only handle the first type.