# Alphabetical order in natbib

Tags: bibtex, natbib, sorting

I have read questions about this, and people say that it is just to include the `natbib` package and the `plainnat` style. For some reason my references will not sort alphabetically. Any help on this would be much appreciated! I am really new to LaTeX ...

My commands:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,norsk]{article}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[comma,authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,vmargin=3.5cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{56}

\end{thebibliography}

\printindex

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The command to print the bibliography in `natbib` is `\bibliography{<your-bib-file>}`. You don't use `\begin{thebibliography} ... \end{thebibliography}`.

So the following document should work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,norsk]{article}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[comma,authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,vmargin=3.5cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
Insert some \cite{} commands here to your citations.

\printindex

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{<your-bib-file>} % Insert the name of your bib file here

\end{document}
```

Comment: I do not have a bib file, because I'm only going to use these for one article. Is it not possible to do it the simple way? Everything works as intended except for the alphabetibal references.

Comment: @Per There is no automatic way to sort citations in the manual `{thebibliography}` environment.  You will save yourself time by creating a bib file with your references even if you don't use it again. See [LaTeX and bibliography management tools](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33619/2693).