# Browsing BibTeX databases

Tags: bibtex, database

Is there a good software for browsing BibTeX databases? I have a *.bib* file with roughly 100 entries and it is becoming harder and harder to look up papers to cite. What I would like is something with a graphical interface that lists the entries in a more readable form. (I prefer open source software. :-)

Any suggestions?

User [tohecz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/11002/tohecz) pointed out there are similar questions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23942/bibliography-tools-that-are-compatible-with-biblatex-and-biber?lq=1) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33619/latex-and-bibliography-management-tools). If people feel this question is redundant, feel free to delete it.

Comment: I'm sure that there's a question on the site somewhere which lists all BibTeX database tools as community wiki. I just can't find it right now. Ah found it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23942/bibliography-tools-that-are-compatible-with-biblatex-and-biber?lq=1 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33619/latex-and-bibliography-management-tools I'm quite against the idea of creating **yet another** CW on bibliography tools. I would make more sense to focus on improving the existing ones.

Comment: My bibliography database currently has some 400 entries, sorts alphabetically. Not really a problem... What exactly is your problem? Perhaps split it up by area?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jabRef for exemple: http://jabref.sourceforge.net/

You have some other software to do it but it's my favorite.

Answer (score 2):

You may import your entries to [Zotero](http://www.zotero.org), either the [stand alone](https://www.zotero.org/download/) program or the [Zotero-extension](https://www.zotero.org/download/) to [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org). The stand alone version has also links to Chrome and Safari browsers, to use these browser to harvest bibliographic entries from the internet.

Also, you may try the new program [Docear](http://www.docear.org/), which combine mind mapping software and Jabref.

[Mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com) is also an option.

Comment: Great, thanks! I'll check it out. (I can't upvote your answer due to low reputation, and I can only accept a single answer. I'll first look through suggestions and then accept one of the answers.)

Answer (score 1):

In my lab Mendeley is used :
[Suscribe to Download](http://www.mendeley.com/en/2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Mac OSX BibDesk (http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net) is an option.

Here is a screenshot of the main window (with biblatex example bibliography)

[image]

and here a screenshot of the window to edit a single entry.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking gor, but I use Linux and Windows. :-)

Comment: JabRef is an alternative for Windows or Linux or Mac, it is written in java and it works on all major platforms.