# Bibliographies from multiple .bib files

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I would like to use multiple `.bib` files for my article, such as `file1.bib`, `file2.bib`.

However, I would like my references not to be separated (such as "Primary sources", "Secondary sources", etc.). These bibliographies just need to be merged into one.

One way to do this is to copy-paste these `.bib` files into one `.bib` file, and this would solve the problem. However, I would like to keep it split into several `.bib` files, by topic (`file1.bib` contains articles on topic1, `file2.bib` contains articles on topic2, and so on).

I tried to do

```
\bibliographystyle{alpha}

\bibliography{file1}
\bibliography{file2}
```

but this just gives me the same bibliography twice!

Answer (score 299):

The correct way to load multiple `bib` files is to use

```
\bibliography{file1,file2}
```

Note the lack of space between the comma and the files!

Comment: What if there is a conflict in bibtexkeys of the two files?

Comment: Only one of them will be include (the first one) and `bibtex` will report a Repeated Entry message and will skip the second one.

Comment: @Guido, may I ask why the space between the comma and the second filename is important?

Comment: @LeoFang otherwise `bibtex` will report a `white space in arguments` and will ignore the bibtex files after the space.

Comment: The lacking space does the trick, thank you

Comment: How do I use a bib file and additional bib items (`\bibitem{}`) in a tex file at the same time?

Comment: @Rob this is a totally different question (not for a comment).

Comment: This is not working for me, I want to load two bib-files, the second got ignored. I am using bibtex and natbib. Any ideas why?

Comment: What if I want each element on a new line, in the TEX source code? I've tried to add `%` and `\\\` at the end of each line, but it does not work. Any other trick I could try? I have as many BIB files as chapters in my documents...

Comment: @Atcold you can use `%` at the end of each line, but do not leave any space between the comma and `%`.  `file1,%`.

Comment: What if the files are in a relative path, say "../Bib Files/" and all the files are in this folder?

Comment: @ZackFair if the folder where the bib files is not in the BIBINPUTS variable, then the path for each file should be specified

Comment: Thanks. That worked. just had to replace every file with .../Bib Files/filename

Comment: I should have read your note about the lack of space.  I spent 2 hours trying to debug it.

Answer (score 49):

If you use the [biblatex](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex) package and need to load multiple bib files, each bib file needs to be loaded separately via an `\addbibresource` instruction:

```
\addbibresource{file1.bib}
\addbibresource{file2.bib}
```

For more information, see section 3.6.1, "Resources", of the reference manual of the [biblatex](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex) package.

---

*Addendum, March 2024*: The section on "Resources", which was numbered 3.6.1 when I posted this answer back in Feb. 2016, is numbered **3.8.1** in the *current* version of the [biblatex](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) reference manual.

Comment: See also [Is there any advantage to using \addbibresource over \bibliography?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21439/35864) for more differences between `\bibliography` and `\addbibresource` in `biblatex.`