# multiple bibliography in thesis: Bibtex items are all shown

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am writing a thesis. There is one main tex file

`thesis.tex`

and there are multiple folders, each one including a tex file and a bib file to constitute one chapter of my thesis:

`Folder_1:  Chapter_1.tex    Bib_1.bib`

`Folder_2:  Chapter_2.tex    Bib_2.bib`

At the end of  `thesis.tex` file I add the following line

`\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Folder_1/Bib_1, Folder_2/Bib_2}`

**First issue** is that, only  the content of Bib_1 is shown up in references of my thesis.

**Second issue** is that all the bibtex items in Bib_1 file are shown in the reference of my thesis, whether that bibtex item is cited or not cited in my thesis.

How can I resolve the above issues.

Answer (score 1):

For the first issue, there should be no space between the file names, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91655/16895.

For the second issue, if you want to list all records in your bibliography you can include `\nocite{*}` somewhere in your document.