# Using two .bib files with biblatex package

Tags: biblatex, files

I am currently using

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
```

and I have two different  `.bib` files:

```
First_bib_File.bib
Second_bib_File.bib
```

The following command does not work

```
\addbibresource{First_bib_File.bib ,  Second_bib_File.bib}
```

What alternative command should I use to simultaneously use the two `.bib` files?

Comment: Try `\addbibresource{First_bib_File.bib}` `\addbibresource{Second_bib_File.bib}`.

Comment: Just do `\addbibresource{First_bib_File.bib}\addbibresource{Second_bib_File.bib}`. I.e. call `\addbibresource` separately on each file. There really must be a duplicate for this.

Comment: There is [Is there any advantage to using \addbibresource over \bibliography?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21439/35864), where lockstep notes: "Contrary to `\bibliography`, one can't use a comma-separated list to load multiple `.bib` files (`\bibliography{bibfile1,bibfile2}`). Instead, one must invoke `\addbibresource` multiple times."

Comment: @Mico I'm not so sure maybe there should at least be a note in [Bibliographies from multiple .bib files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84099/35864), the question I linked to only mentions the issue in passing. ...

Comment: @moewe - I've added a biblatex-focused answer to the posting in question.

Comment: @Mahdi Can you please confirm that everything works as expected if you have one `\addbibresource` for each file?

Comment: the answer by @Ondrian works very well.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that, I have closed your question as a duplicate then.