# Create Sub-bibliography file from a main bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

Say, I have a main (large) bibliography file, `Large.bib`, I include in TeX as

```
\bibliography{Large.bib}
```

how do I crate another sub-bibliography file, `SubBib.bib` that contains the entries which are being cited in the main TeX?

Comment: Take a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84099/bibliographies-from-multiple-bib-files I think it is a duplicate

Comment: It's not how to add multiple bib files, rather, how can I crate the sub-bib from a main bib file.

Comment: I thought you didn't use the language well... but I suppose mine is the problem... You can just copy paste I suppose... may be some non-latex tools too will help. I ca do a fast program to do that for you but we are out of community subject. May be someone has to suggest something from inside this forum.

Comment: take a look here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41821/creating-bib-file-containing-only-the-cited-references-of-a-bigger-bib-file