# Can't open reference.aux with 2 bib files in another directory

Tags: bibtex, compiling

I have 2 .bib files in a directory called `RequiredFiles`. One level back from this I have a file called `Backmatter.tex` which loads the bib like this:

`\bibliography{RequiredFiles/refs1}`

This works fine but as soon as I introduce the second bib file via

`\bibliography{RequiredFiles/refs1}`

`\bibliography{RequiredFiles/refs2}`

My compiler claims it can't open `main.aux`. What's this about?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short compilable TeX code and do not forget to show both used bib files. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to suppose what's happening in your case because you haven't provided any MWE (minimal working example). Also it's not clear what you exactly want.

If you want just to create a bibliography from several files, please try to use

```
\bibliography{RequiredFiles/refs1,RequiredFiles/refs2}
```

See also [Bibliographies from multiple .bib files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84099/bibliographies-from-multiple-bib-files). While loading files separately, as you provided, is also compiled for me fine (MikTeX) but bibliography items are taken incorrectly: only from first file).

If you want to create multiple bibliographies in the same document, please see [Creating multiple bibliographies in the same document](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Creating_multiple_bibliographies_in_the_same_document)