# How to combine two .bib data files

Tags: biber, better-bibtex

I Have two `bib` data files - How can I make my bibtex or other use then both?
In the old days, I could've used cut and past.
would biber help?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean *.bib* files. This question has already been addressed here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84099/bibliographies-from-multiple-bib-files. I hope it helps.