# Bibtex not running after upgrading Ubuntu from 13.04 to 13.10

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, texlive, biber, ubuntu

I'm having problems with my latex installation on Ubuntu 13.10.
Have been using it successfully for a while on Ubuntu 13.04,
after I updated bibtex doesn't seem to work.

The error I get is:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
The top-level auxiliary file: paper.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file paper.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file paper.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file paper.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

I have removed all texlive packages from my system and re-installed texlive-full and kile without success.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Edit1:
Example of .tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % File encoding, you should try to stick to utf8.

\usepackage{csquotes} % Needed for biblatex
\usepackage[maxnames= 10, minnames = 10]{biblatex} % Modern bibliography facilities (you may change style to numeric). change to old bibtex if you insist on using that.
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{mathtools} % All your math related needs
\usepackage{tikz} % Draw figures, required for cover page
\usepackage{subfig} % Subfloats

\addbibresource{bibliography} 

\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\section{test}
Citation\cite{Pironneau1984}

\cleardoublepage
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And bibliography.bib:

```
@article{Pironneau1984,
author = {Pironneau, O.},
journal = {Springer-Verlag},
title = {{Optimal Shape Design for Elliptic Systems}},
year = {1984}
}
```

**Solution:**

I found a solution to this problem when you suggested running biber.

```
sudo apt-get install biber
```

and the bibliography started working again, even without the .bib extension. Not sure why I had to install it separately as it was working fine before.

Thanks for the suggestions @CV4, @Māris Ozols & @MMA!

As explained by @jon the default engine is now biber intead of bibtex which explains why the biber packages is needed.

Comment: I do not think that it has anything to do with Ubuntu. Please let us know the contents of your main file. I suspect that you did not put the commands to specify  the relevant BibTeX files. And welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Does the paper.aux file actually contain these commands?

Comment: @MMA Thanks! I have tried this on files I ran successfully just a few weeks ago and I'm unable to get the bibliography working.  I added a shorter versions of the files above. I think I included all the relevant packages.

Comment: @MārisOzols No paper.aux does not contain these commands.

Comment: @user39581 I am not very sure, but I have a strong suspicion that the problem lies with the line `\addbibresource{bibliography}`. You specify a resource, which is not available. Change in syntax in the upgraded version? Because, when using `\addbibresource` (which was introduced in biblatex v1.2), *ﬁles must be speciﬁed with their full name, including the extension*. Please see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21439/is-there-any-advantage-to-using-addbibresource-over-bibliography).

Comment: I added the .bib extensions and the problem is the same. 
Tried replacing it with \bibliography{bibliography} and the problem still persists.
I found [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142583/bibtex-not-running-after-upgrading-ubuntu-from-13-04-to-13-10) unanswered question, which might be the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using `biblatex` instead of regular `bibtex`. That means two things:

1. You have to specify file extension when you add the *.bib file: `\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}`.
2. You have to call `biber paper` from command line to compile the bibliography.

After that, just compile your paper again and see if it works.

Answer (score 4):

You are using biblatex, then you have to define a backend for biblatex. I think you have to see a warning at compiling like this: `Package biblatex Warning: No "backend" specified, using Biber backend.`

So I think the best way will be configuring your Editor (kile, if I read right) to use `biber` as processor for your bibliography. Your compile-chain will be then:

```
pdflatex paper.tex -> biber paper -> pdflatex paper.tex -> pdflatex paper.tex
```

Further you can clearly define biber as your `biblatex` backend by adding the option

```
backend=biber
```

to `\usepackage[...]{biblatex}`.

Please also think about defining the bibencoding, like you specify your inputenc, by passing option

```
bibencoding=utf8
```

to the same `\usepackage` command.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I didn't get the warning but I have added the options as you suggested!

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that you still can use BibTeX if needed or so desired; the default engine is now `biber`, so it defaults to that if you don't make an explicit declaration, but you could have this in your preamble:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, % <--
  maxnames=10, minnames=10]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
```

and, after `begin{document}`, the standard

```
\printbibliography
```

Then you compile with the normal (or 'old') tool chain:

```
latex  file.tex
bibtex file.aux
latex  file.tex
latex  file.tex
```

And things will work normally unless you use a (`biblatex`) bibliography style that specifically requires `biber` as the engine.

Comment: I see. That explains why I needed to install it separately.