# Biber does not find bib file

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, texstudio, biber

I would like to set-up TeXstudio so that Biber is compiling my `biblatex` bibliography which I exported from Citavi. Unfortunately Biber always looks for a Bibtex formated `*.bib` file.

## Example

```
\documentclass[
paper=a5,
twoside=on,
DIV=calc,
fontsize=10pt,
BCOR=15.0mm,
parskip=half,
cleardoublepage=empty,
headsepline
]
{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}

%   BIBLIOGRAPHY 
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes,english=british]{csquotes} 
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,natbib=true,doi=true,]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{refrences} 

\begin{document}
    This and that~\cite{Umwel.2013}
    
    \include{content/appendix/bibliography}
\end{document}
```

## Biber Log

```
Prozess gestartet: biber.exe "main"

INFO - This is Biber 2.16
INFO - Logfile is 'main.blg'
INFO - Reading 'main.bcf'
INFO - Found 4 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'refrences' for section 0

ERROR - Cannot find 'refrences'!
INFO - ERRORS: 1

Prozess endete mit Fehler(n)
```

## TeXstudio Settings

[image]
[image]

## Question

I think something is still not correct with my enviroment settings or there are still problems with privileges admin vs user, but I don't know where to look at. I also checked of course that the file `refrences.bib` is available in the same folder and level as my `main.tex`. Can you please help me?

Comment: you need the full filename so addbibresource{references.bib}

Comment: as your log shows you are using biber not bibtex. It is not that you are running teh wrong command, you just supplied the wrong filename as biber needs the full name and doesn't add .bib

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Want to type up a quick answer. Surprisingly I could not find a duplicate question. (The fact that `\addbibresource` needs the `.bib` file extension is mentioned in many answer, quite prominently in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21439/35864 for example, but I did not manage to find a question that focuses solely on this.)

Comment: @moewe done but I wonder if I should change the title to "biblatex fails to find bibliography file" or some such. The current title won't help anyone find this.

Comment: The `Looking for bibtex format file 'refrences' for section 0` actually means that Biber is looking for a `.bib` file and not a different type of file format it supports (`.biblatexml`). The "format" might be a bit confusing here. Note also that while there is a difference between BibTeX and `biblatex` the file format for `.bib` files is usually still called BibTeX no matter if you use it with BibTeX or `biblatex`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the full filename so

`\addbibresource{references.bib}`

As your log shows, you are using biber not bibtex. It is not that you are running the wrong command, you just supplied the wrong filename as biber needs the full name and doesn't add `.bib` automatically.