# How to center section titles of an article without centering its references title

Tags: biblatex, citing, natbib, titlesec

I aim to center section titles of an article while still aligning the reference title left. I've tried to define something like \titleformat*{\sectionc}{\centering\large\bfseries} and \titleformat*{\section}{\large\bfseries}. It doesn't work. Could anyone help? Many thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\centering\large\bfseries}
\usepackage[authordate,autocite=inline,backend=biber, natbib]{biblatex-chicago} 
\bibliography{ee.bib}
\begin{document}
\section{Mass}
\cite{goossens1994latex}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

```
@book{goossens1994latex,
  title={The LATEX companion},
  author={Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  volume={1},
  year={1994},
  publisher={Addison-Wesley Reading}
}
```

Comment: Off-topic: You may want to replace `\bibliography{ee.bib}` with `\addbibresource{ee.bib}`.

Comment: Good advice. Glad to substitute \bibliography with \addbibresource. Thanks again! [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21439/is-there-any-advantage-to-using-addbibresource-over-bibliography)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may achieve your formatting objective by inserting the instruction

```
\titleformat*{\section}{\raggedright\large\bfseries}
```

immediately before the `\printbibliography` statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I quite appreciate the solution for its brevity.