# Tool for generating a website's BibTex using the URL?

Tags: bibtex, urls, tools

Is there an existing tool for generating BibTeX of a website using its URL? What I'm thinking is something like a web tool or a Python script that does this.

Comment: Related: [What are good sites to find citations in BibTex format?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/143)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm using [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/), a Firefox plugin, to collect and maintain my references. It has to possiblity to export to BibTeX and to generate an entry from a website.
It supports several online formats for references, like Google Scholar or the IEEE Explorer website and can extract the data from them directly. For general websites it produces a generic entry.

For example it generated this entry from this very page:

```
@misc{_citing_????,
    title = {citing - Tool for generating a website's {BibTex} using the {URL?} - {TeX} - {LaTeX} - Stack Exchange},
    url = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32955/tool-for-generating-a-websites-bibtex-using-the-url},
    howpublished = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32955/tool-for-generating-a-websites-bibtex-using-the-url}
}
```

Comment: What package are you using "url" never works for me.

Comment: @Magpie: I'm using `hyperref` which also uses `url`, but your bibliography style is what's important here, i.e. what code it does create from the `url` entry.

Comment: You may want to mention [Zoterobib](https://zbib.org/), which allows to access the same functionalities without having to install anything.

Comment: I just wish Zotero wouldn't make the BibTeX export such a hassle (save, export, to file, open file, copy BibTeX... ). I just want a browser plugin button that copies the BibTeX to my clipboard and saves the thing to my Zotero library

Answer (score 29):

**A generic (reference manager and browser independent) solution:**

1. Create a new bookmark in the bookmark panel of your browser.
2. Name it (" ➜ " or whatever).
3. URL: Insert this:

   ```
   javascript:"use strict";(function(){var _document$querySelect,_document$querySelect2,_document$querySelect3;function copyToClipboard(text){window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter",text)}function jsDate2bibTex(date){var dd=date.getDate();var mm=date.getMonth()+1;var yyyy=date.getFullYear();if(dd<10){dd="0"+dd}if(mm<10){mm="0"+mm}return yyyy+"-"+mm+"-"+dd}function date2YearTex(date){var yyyy=date.getFullYear();return""+yyyy}var title=document.title;var url=document.URL;var author_tag=document.querySelector("[name=author]");var author=author_tag==null?"":author_tag.content;var today=new Date;var urldate=jsDate2bibTex(today);var publishedTime=(_document$querySelect=document.querySelector('meta[property="article:published_time"'))===null||_document$querySelect===void 0?void 0:_document$querySelect.getAttribute("content");var someTimeTag=(_document$querySelect2=document.querySelector("time[datetime]"))===null||_document$querySelect2===void 0?void 0:_document$querySelect2.getAttribute("datetime");var someTimeTagWithoutDatetime=(_document$querySelect3=document.querySelector("time"))===null||_document$querySelect3===void 0?void 0:_document$querySelect3.innerHTML;var lastModifiedTime=document.lastModified;var pageTime=new Date(publishedTime||someTimeTag||someTimeTagWithoutDatetime||lastModifiedTime);var date=jsDate2bibTex(pageTime);var year=date2YearTex(pageTime);var title_key=title.replace(/[^0-9a-z]/gi,"");var citationKey=title_key+"-"+date;var type="@Online";var filename=":./references/"+window.location.pathname.slice(1).replace(/\//g,"-")+".html:html";var title_tex=title.replace(/\u00e4/g,'\\"a').replace(/\u00c4/g,'\\"A').replace(/\u00f6/g,'\\"o').replace(/\u00d6/g,'\\"O').replace(/\u00fc/g,'\\"u').replace(/\u00dc/g,'\\"U').replace(/\u00DF/g,'\\"s');var bibTexEntry=type+" {"+citationKey+",\r  title = {"+title_tex+"},\r  date = {"+date+"},\r  year = {"+year+"},\r"+(author?"  author = {"+author+"},\r":"")+"  file = {"+filename+"},\r  url = {"+url+"},\r  urldate = {"+urldate+"}\r}";copyToClipboard(bibTexEntry)})();
   ```
4. Load the page you want to cite.
5. Click on the new bookmark button.
6. Copy the selected text to clipboard and press [ENTER].
7. Paste the BibLaTeX entry into

- your .bib file.
- JabRef: Just paste it into the open bibliography table.
- Zotero: Go to 'file' -> 'import from clipboard'.

**Sample output:**

```
@Online {UsingBibTeXashortguide-2015-11-02,
 title = {Using BibTeX: a short guide},
 date = {2015-11-02},
 author = {Martin J. Osborne},
 file = {:./references/osborne-latex-BIBTEX.HTM.html:html},
 url = {https://www.economics.utoronto.ca/osborne/latex/BIBTEX.HTM},
 urldate = {2018-03-17}
}
```

---

PS.: I hosted this on GitHub: https://github.com/dmstern/html2biblatex.
Feel free to fork, star, contribute! :)

---

**Update 2018:**
I optimized the code a bit. Could you guys please test it and report issues to https://github.com/dmstern/html2biblatex/issues? Thank you! :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Would this work in any browser?

Comment: Hi, Torbjørn T.!
I tested it with Google Chrome. Works fine for me. 
Sorry, no idea, if this works with other browsers.

Comment: Doesn't work in Firefox (28) on Linux Mint.

Comment: @Bruno:
Sorry, there was a problem with some code escape characters.
I created a [git repository](https://github.com/dmstern/html2biblatex) to file my script and updated my answer.
Could you please try this version again? Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel: It works now!

Comment: @Daniel I started using your tool and I had few suggestions, so I started an issue in your repository, to be seen here: https://github.com/dmstern/html2biblatex/issues/2

Comment: @FanaticD ✔️ done.

Comment: Amazingly useful bookmark. Take my upvote.

Answer (score 8):

This chrome [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bibtex-entry-from-url/mgpmgkhhbjgkpnanlmlhibjfgpdpgjec) I wrote sometime ago tries to address this.
It creates a BibTeX entry from the active URL and copies it to clipboard automatically.There are three options to create a BibTeX entry from the active URL:

- either press the extension button in the browser
- right-click in the webpage and copy the bibtex to clipboard
- assign a keyboard shortcut to the extension from Chrome menu to automatically copy the BibTeX entry of the active URL.

Example:

For http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/packaging.html we get:

@misc{Packa3:Online,
author = {},
title = {Packaging - Google Chrome},
howpublished = {\url{https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/packaging}},
month = {},
year = {},
note = {(Accessed on 06/07/2014)}
}

Comment: @clement thanks for the feedback. I could add some option to select the format. I was using online before, but for my personal needs misc was better. It should be easy to have it as an option though. Since I am not really an experienced TeX user, what are the candidate formats you would recommend (fields etc.)?

Answer (score 3):

This site allows you to create a citation from a URL and then export it as a bibtex reference:

https://www.citethisforme.com/apa

Comment: Unfortunately, this service does not offer bibtex export anymore…

Answer (score 2):

Also, https://www.refme.com/ allows you to generate a list of references online from urls and export it to a BibTex file when you are done.

Comment: Unfortunately, this service now links to https://www.citethisforme.com/, which makes this answer an exact duplicate of [Jonathan's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223328/34551).

Answer (score 1):

(Moved here from [duplicate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/629546/edit))

One can use a browser extension:

#### Some for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=bibtex)

##### [CurrentPageToBibTeX](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/currentpagetobibtex/)

- parses HTML meta tags
- doesn't always work
- fast setup

##### Cite This!

- couldn't get it to work, but has many users

##### [BibItNow](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/bibitnow/)!

- lots of options
- seems to work well
- urldate, @online have to be enabled
- best for Firefox, in my opinion

#### A few for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/bibtex)

##### [BibTeX entry from URL](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bibtex-entry-from-url/mgpmgkhhbjgkpnanlmlhibjfgpdpgjec)

- copies to clipboard
- not many, but useful options (e.g. for date format and @online)
- works best, in my opinion (in 2021)

##### [BibItNow](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bibitnow/bmnfikjlonhkoojjfddnlbinkkapmldg)!

- Specs: same as Firefox
- I did not test it

In the end, the entries will most likely need [manual editing](https://clauswilke.com/blog/2015/10/02/bibtex). E.g. author or publication date are reliably captured only when tagged in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I've created the [simple URL to BibTeX webapp](https://karlosos.github.io/url_to_bibtex/) which generates basic BibTeX entry based on URL:

[image: app]

The source code is available [here](https://github.com/karlosos/url_to_bibtex).

Answer (score 0):

[getbibtex](https://www.getbibtex.com/) can easily do the job. But it is not as detailed as [bibme](https://www.bibme.org/) does. However the information is inconsistent from bibme.org. you might manually edit/correct some.