# Referencing user guide

Tags: bibtex, natbib

Can someone help me to reference this user guide in LaTeX? I'm searching for a tutorial of how to reference a user guide, but can't find one. Does it fall in the category of article?

```
MIT Java Wordnet Interface (JWI)
User’s Guide
Version 2.2.x
Mark A. Finlayson
(markaf@alum.mit.edu)
November 16, 2011
```

---

The bibliography is set by BibTeX with the style `plainnat` (requires `natbib`)

I've used TexStudio to generate the citation. It was generated as *MIT Java Wordnet Interface (JWI) Users Guide.* using the code below:

```
@manual{jwimit,
ALTauthor = {Mark A. Finlayson},
title = {MIT Java Wordnet Interface (JWI) User’s Guide},
date = {November 16, 2011},
OPTlanguage = {English},
OPTversion = {Version 2.2.x},
OPTorganization = {MIT},
OPTpagetotal = {10},
OPTpubstate = {November 16, 2011},
}
```

Comment: one suggestion off the top of my head: e-mail the author if you can't google it

Comment: I googled it even on scholar, was hoping to find an the bibtex export, thats how i do but did not got it, does it fall in category of article??

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use? Or do you use `biblatex`? `biblatex` provided the entry type `manual`

Comment: And which bibliography style?

Comment: `plainnat` provides the entry `techreport`

Comment: Organise bibliography with [web and Desktop tools](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207/15717). Sometimes for rare references, type `bibtex fields` manually using any [latex editor](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/15717). I use TeXmaker for this purpose.

Comment: I've updated the question with a sample of how it was generated. But, there is no author attached with the citation, is it normal??

Comment: There is no entry `ALTauthor` or `OPT....` Remove the prefixes `ALT` and `OPT` and it will work.

Comment: Right ok, its appearing like this now "Mark A. Finlayson. MIT Java Wordnet Interface (JWI) Users Guide. MIT.", I think it should be ok

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, with the help of the comments above, this solution was obtained:

```
@manual{jwimit,
author = {Mark A. Finlayson},
title = {MIT Java Wordnet Interface (JWI) User’s Guide},
date = {November 16, 2011},
language = {English},
version = {Version 2.2.x},
organization = {MIT},
pagetotal = {10},
pubstate = {November 16, 2011},
}
```