# What tools can (automatically) retrieve BibTeX formatted references from MathSciNet?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

There are a few tools that will automatically retrieve BibTeX-formatted references from MathSciNet. BibDesk is offered with TeXShop, but only works on a Mac.  Are there similar tools that work for Unix/Linux or for Windows?  There are a few applications written as stand-alones that get the job done:
[mscget](https://github.com/pbelmans/mscget) (requires python), [bibupdate](https://bitbucket.org/AndrewsBucket/bibupdate), bibget (a shell script).

JabRef can retrieve references from a number of archives, but
MathSciNet is not listed among these resources.

Some potential tools are mentioned in this answer to
[What are good sites to find citations in BibTex format?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207/579),
listed under "Reference managers that allow BibTeX export/import".
MathSciNet is not included among the archives covered, although
it is mentioned as a resource from which BibTeX-formatted references
can be downloaded manually.

**Note**:  I work for Mathematical Reviews / MathSciNet.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  "user142039" isn't a very informative "name", and easily mistyped.  you might choose something that's easier to recognize.  (doesn't have to be your real name.)

Comment: Hmm.  I had expected my name to follow me from math.stackexchange.  It should be displayed now.  Thanks for drawing my attention to this.

Comment: Papers (from Labtiva) does, but it's $80. available for Mac/Win

Comment: @Naphaneal [Papers] (http://www.papersapp.com/) looks very much like the [Papers Reference Manager] (https://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/author-zone/papers--reference-management-for-authors/4116)  available from Springer.  Are they the same?  or related?

Comment: same software. Springer does link to the developer site.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can try *zotero* (https://www.zotero.org/), a free cross-platform reference management.

Answer (score 1):

There is [bibretrieve](https://github.com/pzorin/bibretrieve) which works in Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

[KBibTeX](https://userbase.kde.org/KBibTeX) is a bibliography editor for KDE that supports retrieving bibliographic information from various sources, including mathscinet.

Answer (score 0):

Many years ago, I adapted Refbase to a mathematical setting, which included writing import plugins for MathSciNet and the arXiv.  My adapted version can be found [on github](https://github.com/loopspace/RefBase).  It is, however, quite old now.