# How to cite Springer's "Encyclopedia of Mathematics"

Tags: citing

Can you provide a bibtex-template for citing [Springer's "Encyclopedia of Mathematics"](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Main_Page) that can be used in scientific articles?

Comment: Did you looked at the references listed here http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/143/34551 or to follow the advices at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3587/34551 ?

Comment: It's Springer and EMS Press, albeit it is not clear from Impressum

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend referring to the specific pages of the Encyclopedia you got your Information from but in general something like this might work:

```
@misc{EncyMath,
author = {{Springer Verlag GmbH, European Mathematical Society}},
title = {{Encyclopedia of Mathematics}},
howpublished = {Website},
note = {URL: \url{https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/}. Accessed on 2016-10-11}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative based on the imperfect analogue of the [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/cite.html). It uses the [Cauchy inequality](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Cauchy_Schwarz_inequality) as an example.

```
@InCollection{cauchy-encyc-maths,
author       =  {{European Mathematical Society}},
title        = {{Cauchy inequality}},
booktitle    =  {{Encyclopedia of Mathematics}},
howpublished =  {\url{http://encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=Cauchy_inequality\&oldid=28864}},
month        = feb,
year         =  {2021},
publisher    =  {EMS Press}
```

}