# Sciencedirect software

Tags: biblatex

I had a problem with my tex works.
I'm currently working on mathematical project in my pHd with Winedt, and my professor told me that there is a software that I need to download that I can work with it and he told me that I must download it, this software is belong to [sciencedirect.com](http://sciencedirect.com) and as I know is sciencedirect has it's own tex software so I still searching for it since the last three days and I cannot found it, so can any one help me to download the sciencedirect software or give me a link or something like that.
Please can any one help me ASAP.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Science direct has a Bibtex export as far as i know. That's it.

Comment: If your professor tells you to downlod software without explaining what it does, how it works and *why you need it*, he assumes you know all that. That would make him an idiot, as he wouldn't have had to tell you.  You should have asked him/her right at that time.

Comment: so can you give me how to use this bibtex and if there is an example and i'll be so gratefull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you google for `sciencedirect latex` or `sciencedirect bibtex`, you will get some useful links. Ask you teacher which material s/he was referring to.

[LaTeX instructions by Elsevier](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions) (Elsevier is the publisher that operates sciencedirect.com.) On these pages you find some LaTeX style files to use with articles to be published by Elsevier, as well as instructions.

[Exporting document citations](http://help.sciencedirect.com/Content/art_export.htm) How to extract citations from sciencedirect.

[7 tips for simplified LaTeX submissions](https://www.elsevier.com/connect/7-tips-for-simplified-latex-submissions) by Elsevier, refers also to Sciencedirect

If the point is to find citations suitable for BiBTeX, see
[What are good sites to find citations in BibTex format?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/143/what-are-good-sites-to-find-citations-in-bibtex-format)